JWT token set in the cookie gets removed on page refresh
I am setting a JWT token in the cookie from the backend, and it gets set correctly the first time. However, when the page is refreshed, the cookie is automatically removed from the browser.
Can anyone help me understand why the cookie is disappearing after a refresh and how I can resolve this issue?
here is the code
                    response.set_cookie(
                    key='auth_token',
                    value=token,
                    domain='http://localhost:3000', 
                    expires=expires_str,
                    secure=False,
                    httponly=False,
                    samesite='None',
                    )

I have tried different parameters that are passed while setting the cookie, but none of them work.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
